# In python, what does this mean: a = L[x]

Tags: python

I have this piece of code:

```py
def sum(L):
    for x in range(len(L) //2):
        a = L[x]
        b = L[-x + 1]
```

what does these two lines of code mean:

```
a = L[x]
b = L[-x + 1]
```

Comment: it means accessing an list element using index

Comment: it means you're assigning the variable a the value of L's element at index x

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar that's pretty harsh mate. OP is new to SO.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

Comment: To help. you with your question, you may want to try [example1](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) and [example2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list/), [example3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-list-methods-append-and-extend?rq=1)

Comment: I keep waiting for someone to find a dupe… but nobody has yet.

Answer (score 0):

```py
a = L[x]
```

Index into variable `L` (like a list or a dictionary) at value `x` and store that value into variable `a`.

Similarly for b:

```py
b = L[-x + 1]
```

This means to index into `L` at value `-x + 1` and store it into a variable `b`.

Answer (score 0):

That is some indexing. We use that to pull out a specific part of some data.
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
my_dictionary = {"element_one": 1, "element_two": 2}

This may be a little confusing, but you can call that data by indexing it, the basic of it is that this

```
print(my_list[0])
```

Will return 1. The first element will start at 0 and keep ongoing.

```
print(my_list[2])
```

That would return 3. As for the dictionary, it calls a specific value.

```
print(my_dictionary["element_two"])
```

Will return 2. If you have any questions, feel free to message me!

Answer (score 0):

`L[x]` is a [subscription expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions), useful for getting values out of [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) and [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), among other things.

A subscription expression is one where the first part (`L` here) is an object that *supports subscription*. An object that supports subscription can be a built in type such as a list or dictionary. It can also be a user-defined type that has a `__getitem__` method.

### In your code:

```
def sum(L):
    for x in range(len(L) //2):
        a = L[x]
        b = L[-x + 1]
```

`x` is a value that iterates from 0 to half the length of the list `L`. So `L[x]` is just going to keep walking up `L` until it gets to about half way. But `-x + 1` is going to be `1`, then `0`, then `-1`, etc. Since lists support negative subscripts, this will get you the last half of the list, one entry at a time. (But the first two values, `L[1]` and `L[0]` may be bugs if you're planning to add `a + b`.)

### Details from the documentation:

> If the primary [that means `L`] is a mapping, the expression list must evaluate to an object whose value is one of the keys of the mapping, and the subscription selects the value in the mapping that corresponds to that key. (The expression list is a tuple except if it has exactly one item.)

```
>>> L = {'dictionaries': 'are cool', 'and so': 'are you'}
>>> L['dictionaries']
'are cool'
```

> If the primary is a sequence, the expression list must evaluate to an integer or a slice (as discussed in the following section).

```
>>> L = [1,2,3,4]
>>> L[3]
4
```

If you try to use subscription on an object that is *not* subscriptable, you'll probably get a `TypeError`:

```
>>> 1[3]
>>> 1[3]
<stdin>:1: SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not subscriptable; perhaps you missed a comma?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

(But be careful! Strings are sequences, and therefore subscriptable!)

```
>>> 'hello'[3]
'l'
```